# Show that the limit equals zero

Tags: limits

I need to prove that the following function:

$$ f(x_1,x_2)= \frac{4x_1^2x_2^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$$

has a limit 0 in (0, 0).

The book argues the following:

$$ f(x_1,x_2)= \frac{4x_1^2x_2^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}} \leq 2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} < \epsilon $$

Can somebody explain how they come up with $$2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$$

As that is the part I do not understand unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true it $x_1=2$ and $x_2=1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Don't we work near the origin?

Comment: @mrs True, but nevertheless it isn't true in general, so one should make use of the tininess of both $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I got the point! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

We may suppose, since it is the limit at $(0,0)$ we seek, that $x_1^2+x_2^2\le 1$, hence $|x_1|,|x_2|\le 1$, so
$$\frac{4x_1^2x_2^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\le \frac{4x_1^2x_2^2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\le \frac{4|x_1 x_2|}{x_1^2+x_2^2 }\, \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\le 2 \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the argument of your book (at least not for $x_1,x_2$ unspecified in $\mathbb R$), but $$|x_1x_2|\leq \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2),$$
and thus $$\frac{x_1^2x_2^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}\leq\frac{1}{4}(x_1^2+x_2^2)\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}.$$

Comment: Nice hint! Indeed, you got the rescue from what we know about AM and GM. +1

Comment: Thank you. Is your first equation a general property? I did not know this one before.

Comment: @Bryan95: Yes, it's equivalent to the fact that $(x_1-x_2)^2\geq 0.$